# Appending the text of a file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am using Shell scripting. I tried the below option.
I want to append the part of a file to another part of a file.

I tried this command to append the content of a file.

Command:

```
 /bin/cat ../../../test_op.txt/sql/part_code.txt >> ../../../PartitioningUtility/log/test_op.txt
```

To append the text of `part_code.txt` to `test_op.txt`.

No errors but the text is not appending.

Any Solution to this problem.

Any other option to append the data of a one file to another

Comment: Does the file `../../../test_op.txt/sql/part_code.txt` contain anything at all?

Comment: I can use >> to append without problem (Bash).

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the results?  The append operator will create the file if it doesn't exist, so you might be creating the file somewhere different from where you think it is.  Demonstrate with `wc ../../../test_op.txt/sql/part_code.txt ../../../PartitioningUtility/log/test_op.txt` before and after your `cat` command.

Comment: Can you do `cd ../../..` and then run the command without all the dot dots? It will be easier to troubleshoot...

Comment: Also, if `which cat` gives the path, you don't need to add the `/bin/` before the `cat` command...

Comment: What does `cat ../../../test_op.txt/sql/part_code.txt` give you? The only reason this would happen is that the file is empty (unless your `cat` binary has been replaced).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to append all content from '/bin/cat ../../../test_op.txt/sql/part_code.txt' to '../../../PartitioningUtility/log/test_op.txt' you could add 'cat' in the beginning:

```
cat ../../../test_op.txt/sql/part_code.txt >> ../../../PartitioningUtility/log/test_op.txt
```

That is assuming that file paths are correct.

Comment: It's hard to see how you copied another answer, but two identical mistakes is also hard to explain.

Comment: Seems that they are just calling `cat` with the full path. I don't think they want to cat the binary too...

Comment: `/bin/cat` *is* `cat`.